# Create Blob column in Sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to create a table in SQLite with blob type column (Content):

```
create table [Files]
(
    Id int identity not null
        constraint PK_File_Id primary key,
    MimeType nvarchar (400) not null,
    Content varbinary (max) null
       constraint DF_File_Content default (0x),
);
```

However the following is not being accepted:

```
    Content varbinary (max) null
       constraint DF_File_Content default (0x),
```

Why?

Comment: Are you sure you're using SQLite? `varbinary` is not a valid type in that engine.

Comment: That doesn't make any difference - you use *almost* anything for a type name - but "max" is reserved for a standard function.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but if you have a primary key column that contains integers, you'll want to declare it as `integer` (rather than `int`) in order to make it an alias of the ROWID.  It's the one case in SQLite where the exact type name matters.

Comment: To supplement dan04's comment, specify *explicitly* "integer primary key".

Comment: One more thing, I lost track of the fact that you want to "create a table in SQLite with blob type column (Content)", but you declare the column Content as "Content varbinary (max) null".  According to https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html, your declared type must include the string "BLOB"; "varbinary" will result in type "NUMERIC" affinity.  (See the link for details.)

Answer (score 1):

"Max" is the name of a standard SQLite3 function, so is not available as part of a type name.

Answer (score 1):

See the syntax reference for the [CREATE TABLE statement](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) and [data types](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).  A [type name](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/type-name.html) can include *numbers* in parentheses (which are ignored), but not the word “MAX”.

It looks like you're trying to use MS SQL Server syntax, and there are several errors in your code:

- As mentioned above, `(max)` is not accepted as part of a type name.  Since value lengths are unconstrained by default, simply omit it.
- `varbinary` gives the column “numeric affinity”.  While such a column *can* store a blob, you'll probably want to declare it as `blob` instead.
- `0x` is not a valid blob literal.  The correct way to write an empty blob is `x''`.
- `identity` is called [`autoincrement`](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html).  And in order to use it, the type name must be `integer` rather than `int`.  The `not null` is redundant: If you try to insert a null value into such a column, you'll get the auto-incremented ROWID instead.

  - **Note**: If you simply need `Id` to have unique values at any given time and don't care if previously-deleted values get re-used, then you can simply declare the column as `integer primary key`, and inserting `null` will fill in the column with an unused integer.  The `autoincrement` keyword prevents the re-use of ROWIDs over the lifetime of the database, more closely matching the semantics of MS SQL's `identity` keyword.  See the discussion at the link above.
- While it's syntactically legal to declare a name for a column constraint, it's not necessary.

Try this:

```
create table [Files]
(
    Id integer primary key autoincrement,
    MimeType nvarchar (400) not null,
    Content blob null default (x'')
);
```

Note that this does not enforce a length limit on a `MimeType` column.  If you need to, add the constraint `check (length(MimeType) <= 400)`.

Comment: Two points:  (1) You are correct about the invalidity of "0x", but why would one want to make the default value of a blob table to an empty blob - why not just take default value of NULL? (2) Why do you say "identity is called autoincrement"?  I don't know if there's any particular reason to use it here, and in fact is in my opinion overused where it is not necessary ("integer primary key not null" will in general get the desired results). Before using it, look at the discussion of the implementation at https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html.  (Apart from these, I endorse all your other points.)

Comment: Actually, I don't even think that the "not null" is needed with "integer primary key".

Comment: @varro: (1) Because it matches the semantics of the original T-SQL code in the question.  (2) I've added a clarifying note for this.

Comment: OK - I think we are in agreement.